# How to sort the blog

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to sort blog by title. The blog does not appear at view. Taxonomy does not has any setting related to sort. What else I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **/blog** path created by the blog module does not have an option sort by title. The easiest way to do this is to use the Views module to create a page view and just build a display of blogs sorted by titles.

Another way, if you're looking to alter the built in **/blog** path created by the blog module, you could use [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to alter the page callback from `blog_page_last()` that's in **blog.pages.inc**.

You can place this code in your custom module:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&items) {
  $items['blog']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_blog_page_title_order';
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_blog_page_title_order() {
  global $user;
  $build = array();

  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $nids = $query
    ->fields('n', array('nid', 'sticky', 'created'))
    ->condition('type', 'blog')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('sticky', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('title', 'ASC')
    ->limit(variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10))
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

  if (!empty($nids)) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
    $build += node_view_multiple($nodes);
    $build['pager'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'pager',
      '#weight' => 5,
    );
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('No blog entries have been created.'));
  }
  drupal_add_feed('blog/feed', t('RSS - blogs'));

  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How about other taxonomy which work exactly like the blog.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "other taxonomy", do you mean taxonomy term pages? (e.g. **/taxonomy/term/1** )

Comment: This a bit complicated. I install uber cart module. Product is auto created in the content type and Catalog is auto created in taxomony. I add a few terms such book, shoe and other in the catalog. When I click Books hyperlink, it will bring me to a list of different book, but it does not sort by title. What should I do?

Comment: If you're talking about the uc_catalog view, you can override the sorting criteria from the Views UI (**admin/structure/views/view/uc_catalog/edit**) if you're talking about your catalog taxonomy you can have views override the default display to sort it however you want (goto the bottom of the Views UI & look for **Taxonomy term**)

Comment: Thank you. Is it implement same code as the blog?

Comment: No, it's just using the Views UI to override the default display for the catalog or taxonomy view.