# How to make the blog post ascending order?

Tags: nodes

By default (without Views), the blog posts are sorted by date: the first post is the latest date.

I need the first post, is the oldest.

**How to achieve this without Views?**

Also I have a custom module to execute an override of blog_page_last() function ([I followed the steps in this page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157372/how-to-sort-the-blog)). But it does not work. It does nothing, nothing at all.
Also directly I modified the `blog_page_last function()` in **File: /modules/blog/blog.pages.inc.** And nothing happens.

Thank in advance.

Comment: try http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue module

Comment: Did you cache flush after overriding the menu router? hook_menu_alter only runs when rebuilding the menu router.

Comment: Yes, i tried it. And nothing happens! Ok, I rephrase my cuestion, [see more, please](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178048/php-sorting-items-of-any-type-of-content).

Comment: Furthermore, the list generated by Nodequeue in itself is useless. I am right? The generated list is useful for Views.

I do not want to use Views!